# Web deployment with Matlab javabuilder

Tags: java, matlab, deployment

I tried the example magicSquare given to create a web app. I used the Tomcat server and the built .war file is imported to eclipse. But when I run the .jsp page it only goes to the UI and the instance which invokes mcr does not run. There the server stops. All the time when the deployed matlab function is called in the servlet it stops.
Can anyone plz help me finding this error!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Is there any exception traces?

Comment: ... Matlab M-code Stack Trace ... com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException: An error occurred while initializing the component. Could not access the MCR component cache. at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.mclInitializeComponentInstance(Native Method) at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.access$900(MWMCR.java:28)java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MagicSquareServlet.doGet(MagicSquareServlet.java:48)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Comment: This is only a part of the stack trace. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe is too late, but it could be useful to someone else... I solved this problem changing the MCR_ROOT_CACHE variable. On my Ubuntu server I set:

```
export MCR_CACHE_ROOT=/path/to/temp/folder
```

Comment: what is the /path/to/temp/folder?